Minimum vertical distance of $f(x)=\log(x) , g(x)=x^2$
As the title suggests that is the question I am asked to answer.
Find the minimum vertical distance of $f(x)=\log(x) , g(x)=x^2$.
Bellow is how I solved it , although it's a pretty basic approach. My question is can we solve this problem in another way ?
my solution
Let $d(x)=|f(x)-g(x)|=|log(x)-x^2|$
we know $\log(x)\leq x-1 <x  $  , $ \forall x \in (0,+ \infty)$
for $0<x \leq 1 \implies x-1 < x^2 \implies x^2>\log(x) , x\in(0,1] $
for $x>1 \implies x^2>x \implies \log(x)<x^2 $
So $\log(x)<x^2 , \forall x \in (0,+\infty)$
And $d(x)$ becomes
$$d(x)=x^2-\log(x)$$
we can take the derivative w.r.t $x$ :
$$d'(x)=2x- \frac{1}{x}$$
Setting it equal to zero we get $d'(x)=0 \iff 2x-\frac{1}{x}=0 $ and since $x>0$ the only solution is $\sqrt{2} \over2$
We can easily see that for $x<\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$ , $d'(x)<0$ and for $x>\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} , d'(x)>0$
$d $  is continuous in its domain so it is decreasing for $x<\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$ and it is increasing for $x>\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$ therefore it has a minimum there . Now we need to calculate $d(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2})=\frac{1}{2}+ \frac{1}{2} \log(2)$ and that sould be our answer.

Can you please explain why for all +ve x, $log x ≤ x+1 ≤ x$. How can $x+1≤x$?

@Gwen seems like I made a typo thanks for noticing and sorry for the confusion

Why would you want "another way"? Note that you don't need to prove first that $\log(x)<x^2 , \forall x \in (0,+\infty)$. The rest of your calculations (re)proves it.
